# Deformation of PTH component pins during handling

Tags: design, components, component-selection

The PCBA drawing specifies 4.23 mm standoff for a PTH component.
Now we encounter deformation issue of the pins during handling due to being slightly touched by operator.

Is there any improvement for the component design to avoid this issue?

Your advice is much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: what about some plastic beads/tubes around the leads? and why is it being handled without a case by careless people anyways?

Comment: Hi PlasmaHH, thanks for your prompt answer! your idea sounds good.

Comment: A "Joggle" - bend in the leads to make sure that the component is mounted a distance from the PCB. Some parts you can buy with a joggle preformed in the leads.

Comment: Hi steve, can you show me some illustration? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My preference in this situation is to machine a fixture that holds the part while it is being soldered.

You can use spacer tubes on the leads (various suppliers including Bivar and there are cheaper ones out there).

You can use spacers that are designed to wash away in aqueous cleaning solution.

You can have a die made to preform the leads or order them. This is commonly done when mounting parts that get very hot, especially on really cheap PCB laminates such as paper-based phenolics. (Photo credit to [this](http://www.mtarr.co.uk/courses/topics/0230_ci/index.html) site).

[image]